# Get Mouse button Click

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to detect mouse button clicks i checked some documentation on Microsoft website and found we can use GetKeyState function to detect button clicks, here's my code.

Not sure what i am doing wrong her but i am not getting anything printed in my Output when i press buttons.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

void CheckMouseButtonStatus()
{
    //Check the mouse left button is pressed or not
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        cout << "left button pressed" << endl;
    }
    //Check the mouse right button is pressed or not
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        cout << "right button pressed" << endl;
    }
}
```

just found a youtube video a buddy was telling about it and i tried it still didn't got anything in Output

```
int main()
{
    //Check the mouse left button is pressed or not
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        cout << "left button pressed" << endl;
    }
    //Check the mouse right button is pressed or not
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        cout << "right button pressed" << endl;
    }
}
```

This one worked but with complications -

```
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        //Check the mouse left button is pressed or not
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
        {
            cout << "left button pressed" << endl;
        }
        //Check the mouse right button is pressed or not
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))
        {
            cout << "right button pressed" << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I tried that as well but didn't got anything in output.

Comment: What is the point of `& 0x80`? From what I can tell from [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), only bit 0 and 15 are relevant, but never bit 7. Shouldn't it rather be `& 0x8000`?

Comment: Sorry those bits thing went over my head, i am still in high school. I checked the same documentation and from there i got this
`VK_BACK
0x08
BACKSPACE key`

Comment: The return value of both GetKeyState and AsyncGetKeyState is "SHORT",according to the documentation. This is a typedef for "short int", which is a 16-bit integer on the Windows platform. Therefore, the bits are numbered 0 to 15. You must check the [most significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit), which is 15, by using `& 0x8000`. See [this page](https://www.bottomupcs.com/chapter01.xhtml) for a tutorial of binary number representation and bit masks.

Comment: That code takes well less than a microsecond to execute, you can't click the button that fast.  You need a loop, `for(;;) { ... }`.  The *correct* way to do it in a console mode app is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput), albeit that the user of your app will have no idea that the mouse might do something useful.  Petzold's "Programming Windows" is a classic.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried it with While loop and it worked and execution is pretty fast as well the only problem is when i press right click + left click then they get recorded continously but when i press left button alone then it will detect only once while for right it will be keep detecting it.

Comment: Congratulations.  Sounds like you have a new question, that happens.

Comment: @SidKaushik: The expression `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` will be true when either bit 0 or 15 is set. However, according to the [official documentation on GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), bit 0 should not be relied upon. It is only provided for compatibility for 16-bit Windows applications (programs that are more than 20 years old). Therefore, you should always only check bit 15 by writing `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000` instead.

Comment: According to the linked documentation, bit 0 is set if the button has been pressed since the previous function call to `GetAsyncKeyState`, and bit 15 is set if the button is currently being pressed. However, bit 0 is unreliable and is only provided for backwards compatibility, so you should only check for bit 15, which tests if the button is currently being pressed. It does not make sense to test for both bits, as you are doing in the code you posted.

Comment: Debugging tip: assign the value returned by `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` to a variable so that you can both test it in your `if` condition and stream it to `cout`.

Comment: Thanks all for suggesting some good things.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) and use a bitwise AND to check if the least significant bit is set, this indicates a new key press, and not one that was previously detected.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Check the mouse left button is pressed or not
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 1)
        {
            std::cout << "left button pressed" << std::endl;
        }
        //Check the mouse right button is pressed or not
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 1)
        {
            std::cout << "right button pressed" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

GetAsyncKeyState is great for simple testing and learning purposes but it's best to use the normal Windows message queue for any input detection.  Keep in mind GAKS is global, it will detect key presses on all processes, not just yours.  Read the remarks on MSDN because sometimes that can cause a problem.

Comment: As pointed out on the page that you linked to, the least significant bit of the return value is only provided for backwards compatibility to 16-bit Windows. It should not be used in 32-bit (or 64-bit) applications, as it is unreliable.